# Conditions for publishing scientific articles

Tags: publications, mathematics

Does sharing part of the results of a study or scientific article affect the publication of this article in the future?

I am asking this question because I wrote a scientific article in mathematics and I want to share part of the results I reached to convince one or more mathematicians of the importance of the article. Perhaps I will find someone to help me publish it.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. I have never heard of anyone making acceptance/rejection decisions for publications taking such things into account.

Comment: "It depends". It depends on your field, the results you're claiming, the norms of practice within your community, and the general policies of your target journal.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing privately with people for feedback and/or collaboration doesn't affect publication. Putting it on a web site might, but even arXiv is mostly acceptable in mathematics (probably not all journals, though and not all fields).

But private sharing is widespread and acceptable everywhere.

And you don't need anyone to "help you publish it" unless it isn't really ready for publication.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing information an article is common and will not affect the publication process with any journal in mathematics.

However, your attitude is wrong and will not help you. You seek "help to publish" an article, and its unclear what that means.

You can reasonably hope for feedback from experts in the relevant mathematical community, but don't expect too much, since everyone is busy with their own thing. The submission process is fairly straight-forward, though, and nobody can give you substantial help with that - in the worst case, you open yourself up to exploitive actors you suggest being co-authors as "publication help".

You should move ahead once your article is done and see what the referee reports say.